# How to get the value from the URL GET parameters in react native webview?

Tags: react-native, url, webview, parameters, get

I have this response

```
webViewState Object {
  "canGoBack": true,
  "canGoForward": false,
  "loading": false,
  "navigationType": "other",
  "target": 65507,
  "title": "السداد بواسطة PayPal - راجع مدفوعاتك",
  "url": "https://example.com/?paymentId=PAYID-L2ILTHQ83R55588UV606981X&token=EC-5EB6693455269621L&PayerID=BLG98CXTZAX8S",
}
```

How can i access paymentId and PayerID parameters from the URL??

I tried this line but it returns undefined for both `const { PayerID, paymentId } = webViewState.url;`

Any help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After getting your data you can do this:

```
var regexp = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,params = {},check;
while (check = regexp.exec(webViewState.url)) {
  params[check[1]] = check[2];
}
console.log("params",params)
```

params will give you a object like this

```
Object {
  "PayerID": "BLG98CXTZAX8S",
  "paymentId": "PAYID-L2ILTHQ83R55588UV606981X",
  "token": "EC-5EB6693455269621L",
}
```

Hope this helps!